# Is $\forall x ((A = \{a | P(a)\} \wedge x \in A ) \rightarrow P(x))$ an axiom of some system?

Tags: logic

In section 1.3 of Vellemans's 'How to Prove it', the author states  the following:

"In general, the statement $y \in {x | P(x)}$ means the same thing as $P(y)$,..."

I couldn't find a proof of this, and wondered if $\forall x ((A = \{a | P(a)\} \wedge x \in A) \rightarrow P(x))$ an axiom of some set theory or a close derivative one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically just by definition. Set theory doesn't actually have set-builder notation directly; "$A=\{a: P(a)\}$" is just shorthand for "$\forall a(a\in A\leftrightarrow P(a))$." And $$\forall a(a\in A\leftrightarrow P(a))\wedge x\in A\rightarrow P(x)$$ is provable just from the basic laws of logic:

- From "$\forall a(a\in A\leftrightarrow P(a))$" we get "$x\in A\leftrightarrow P(x)$" via **universal instantiation**.
- From that in turn we get $x\in A\rightarrow P(x)$, just by unpacking "$\leftrightarrow$" (and applying one of the **$\wedge$-elimination rules** if you want to be picky).
- Finally, we can get $P(x)$ from $x\in A\rightarrow P(x)$ and $x\in A$ via **modus ponens**.

Note that everything except the universal instantiation is basically just *propositional* logic, namely the fact that $$[(p\leftrightarrow q)\wedge p]\rightarrow q$$ is a propositional tautology.

Comment: Doesn't it matter that I have used different variables, $a$ and $x$?

Comment: @supposer Sorry, that was sloppy of me; I've fixed, and added some details. But no, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Don't we want to require this sort of notation to involve some larger set, to avoid Russel's Paradox?

Comment: @aschepler No, not in this situation. What one wants to avoid w/r/t set builder notation is implicitly claiming that the class $\{a: P(a)\}$ is in fact a set. Using a bounded quantifier ($\{a\in b: P(a)\}$) of course does the trick (at least in [$\mathsf{ZF}$-style set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom)). But in this case we're really using set-builder notation only to formulate a hypothesis ("IF the set $A$ is the set of all $a$ such that $P(a)$, THEN ..."), so it's not a problem here. *(And of course we're ultimately translating away from set-builder notation entirely.)*

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Noah, that made the difference; I got it now.

Comment: I haven't seen that quantifier use before, is this how one defines a new domain of discourse? Like "for all where this predicate holds"?